# Microsoft Word Template creation with images

Tags: ms-word

I'm trying to create a MS Word template to be used by our 501c3 group for animal rescue.  We are wanting to copy the pet description text from the web site into the web site (manually, not via a script).  We also want to be able to right click the image from the web site and paste into the Word docx.  However, I need the image to be constrained to the size of the allocated for the image withing the word document.  I'm trying to make this as simple as possible for the person who is printing up the cage cards since they are not technical.  I'm not fluent with MS Word templates so I'm asking you guys for help.

I'm looking for steps or a web site or even a youtube video that would help me.  I've found sites that walk me through the forms creation steps but nothing for the image with constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand, you want an area in the word document that holds a placeholder image that you can easily replace with one from the website.  If that is the case, here's what you need to do:

1. First put a placeholder image in the word template.  Position it in the right place and make sure it is the size you want.
2. Next, when you want to use the new image from the website, first save the website image onto your computer.  Then right-click on the image in the word template and select **Change Picture**.  Select the new picture that you saved on your computer and voila!